# Filtering text files in cmd?

Tags: text, cmd

Is there any way that one can filter a text file in Windows' CMD as with awk in shell script?

I have a somehow large file and I only need the last column from each row. This will be done extremely easy with awk, but I have no means of using that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this our

```
Get-Content .\test.csv | %{ $_.Split(',')[1]; }
```

or for more reference 
check out this site

[[1]: http://windows-powershell-scripts.blogspot.in/2009/06/awk-equivalent-in-windows-powershell.html](http://windows-powershell-scripts.blogspot.in/2009/06/awk-equivalent-in-windows-powershell.html)

Answer (score 1):

This will return every last term after the last comma in a .csv file for example:

```
@echo off
type "file.csv" | repl ".*,(.*)" "$1" >"newfile.txt"
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.